# Trekking Pole vs Nordic Walking Pole

Tags: hiking, walking, trekking-poles

I am taking up hiking again on weekends, and also trying to do more walking to get out of the house of an evening.

I regularly see people doing [Nordic Walking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_walking) in my neighbourhood, and I also see the benefit of trekking poles when on varied terrain ([Bruce Trail](http://brucetrail.org) and the Niagara Escarpement in Ontario, Canada).

[REI](http://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/trekking-poles-hiking-staffs.html) has an interesting article on Trekking Poles, and in the article it states:

> Nordic walking poles are a modified version of trekking poles. REI does not currently carry poles designed for Nordic walking.

But it gives no actual details what the *modifications* are.

So: how is a nordic pole different than a trekking pole?  Can I at all realistically use one for both purposes, and what will I be trading off if I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is my understanding that the Nordic or Exercise Poles are for walking fast and the grip is designed to release quickly forward in stride with a glove like fit and usually have either a rubber or paw type tip. The Trekking or Hiking poles are designed for pushing slightly down on to take pressure off of your lower body with a lighter thinner strap and have a tougher tip for rocks and rough terrain.